# Database replication/synchronization using multiple source nodes for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replication, merge-replication

What would be the approach for synchronization at DB level for a scenario where data from multiple sources (DB nodes) needs to be integrated at a destination DB node when using PostgreSQL?

The PostgreSQL XDB replication server supports single master replication and multi master replication, but this scenario requires syncing multiple sources at one destination.

Comment: I think [pglogical](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/) has that feature (among many others)